# I cannot align paragraphs with images, but links will align perfectly without much intervention

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to write my contact page, it's for a personal website that I write as part of a project for school. I am trying to display little logos of certain social media sites, and my profile name/mail address next to the images. I have set up an unordered vertical list, I have  elements for each individual < li > tag and here comes the problem: Facebook, for example, works fine. The logo is there, and a link to my profile next to it, with the text perfectly aligned vertically right in the center. The problem comes with paragraphs. For my Yahoo Mail address, for example, I cannot provide a link to my profile, so I instead just write my address as simple text between < p >< /p > tags. This text will not align. I don't know what to do. I've been trying stuff out and looking for solutions all over the internet for hours and nothing works. I do admit my HTML and CSS experience is very limited, but please help me. I will attach both my HTML code and the CSS file and I hope someone will take the time to see how they render and maybe help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="Description" content="Pagina de contact">
<meta name="author" content="Matei Popa">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contactstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="navlink">
<div class="img">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/matei.popa.332" target="_blank">
<img class="image" src="img/contact-pg/facebooklogo.jpg" alt="Logo 
Facebook">
</a>
</div>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/matei.popa.332" target="_blank">
Matei Popa 
</a>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="navlink">
<div class="img">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/matei.popa.332/" target="_blank">
<img class="image" src="img/contact-pg/instagramlogo.jpg" alt="Logo 
Instagram">
</a>
</div>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/matei.popa.332/" target="_blank">
matei.popa.332
</a>
</div> 
</li>
<li>
<div class="navlink">
<div class="img">
<a href="https://twitter.com/mateiutz2001" target="_blank">
<img class="image" src="img/contact-pg/twitterlogo.jpg" alt="Logo Twitter">
</a>
</div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/mateiutz2001" target="_blank">
@mateiutz2001
</a>
</div>
</li> 
<li>
<div class="navlink">
<div class="img">
<img class="image" src="img/contact-pg/yahoomaillogo.jpg" alt="Logo Yahoo 
Mail">  
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
<p>alex.matei1808@yahoo.com</p>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="navlink">  
<div class="img">
<img class="image" src="img/contact-pg/gmaillogo.jpg" alt="Logo Gmail">
</div>  
<div class="paragraph"> 
<p>                                                                   
mattx1829@gmail.com
</p>
</div>              
</div>
</li>  
</ul>   
</div>
<!-- add Phone number, Yahoo Mail, Gmail, Whatsapp, Skype, Reddit, Quora -->
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: Sansation;
src: url(../font/Sansation_Regular.ttf)
}

body
{
background-color: #000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

div.container
{
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 40px;
margin: 60px;
align-content: flex-start;


}

ul
{
list-style-type: none;
}

li
{

flex-direction: row;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
float: left;
height: 50px;
}

div.navlink
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
width: 100%;
float: left;
text-align: left;
font-family: Sansation;
font-size: 24px;
padding: 10px;
}


a:link 
{
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: transparent; 
}

a:hover
{
color: #D1DC19;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited
{
color: #E47507;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
color: red;
background-color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
 }

div.img
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;

float: left;
align-content: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

div.paragraph
{
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #FFFFF;
font-family: Sansation;
padding-left: 0px;
width: auto;
height: 100%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
align-content: center;
text-align: center;

}

p
{
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
align-content: center;
}

.image
{
vertical-align: middle;
padding-right: 15px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

[How it looks like now](https://jsfiddle.net/33a6po1o/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a link for your Yahoo email address using `mailto:youremail@address.com`.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_mailto

Your snippet of code for that *li* would then be:

```
<li>
 <div class="navlink">
  <div class="img">
   <a href="https://twitter.com/mateiutz2001" target="_blank">
   <img class="image" src="img/contact-pg/yahoomaillogo.jpg" alt="Logo Yahoo Mail"></a>
  </div>
  <a href="mailto:alex.matei1808@yahoo.com">alex.matei1808@yahoo.com</a>
 </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about this. It works. Thanks!